# What are the Planets?

Tags: plot-explanation, after-earth

In the movie "After Earth" the humans are relocated to another planet. What is that planet and the planet the ship crashes? Is it the Earth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They went to Nova Prime to settle.
And the main part of the movie takes place in Earth, where their shuttle went down.

You can get a look at the [After Earth Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Earth).